# Should my partner explain UK visa refusal in her cover letter for Schengen visa application?

Tags: uk, schengen-visas, visa-refusals, applications

My partner and I are applying for a Schengen visa. Previously, she had a UK visitor visa refusal (the visa officer doubted she will leave the UK after her visit). While the Schengen visa application form does not explicitly ask for previous refusal histories of other countries, is there any need to mention the previous UK visa refusal in her cover letter when applying for the Schengen visa?

It should be noted that when she applied for the UK visa, she was single, studying at college, and did not provide adequate documentation to explain her circumstances at home. It's been five years since then and there has been a change of circumstances like we live together, she has a job, and we traveled to four countries together. This will be her first Schengen visa application. I previously traveled to the Schengen region twice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The usual rule in these situations is to answer, truthfully and concisely, the questions asked, and only the questions asked. Any information they want from you they will ask for in the instructions or on the form.

Answer (score -3):

No, there is no need to do that. UK is not in Schengen. The Schengen Visa Law is specifically for the Schengen Member states. You are supposed to share this information when asked as mentioned below the application form itself doesn’t have this field as of now.

In the Schengen Visa Information they can very well see when was the last time you had gotten a visa in Schengen countries.

Personal experience the Danish embassy asked me about if I had any Schengen Visa Rejection I told them the truth.

If the embassy asks you specifically for any country outside Schengen then you must tell them the truth.
In my opinion do read these codes they are simple and straightforward how and what does the visa format looks like I did it and it will save you a ton of time and resources
Perhaps read Schengen Visa Code if you like to [visa code link](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/EN/legal-content/summary/visa-code.html)

Schengen Application Link does not require you to share anything about your previous refusal of another country outside Schengen Code , check the link [Schengen Application Form](https://www.eeas.europa.eu/sites/default/files/schengen_visa_en.pdf)

On top of that countries introduce their own aliens act

I have added these details , since someone commented to provide link

Thanks

Comment: Advice to read the visa code is something like advice to google something. There is a lot of information but most people will not get out what is useful for them. You need to give much more detail what and where in the code to make it useful.